# Use a .net assembly from a totally unmanaged C++ application?

Tags: c++-cli

Is there any way I can reference and use classes and methods from a managed .net assembly from within a totally unmanaged C++ application? (no /clr)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, and [this gem from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/unmanaged_to_managed.aspx) should prove helpful

You need a **CCW (COM callable wrapper).**

Answer (score 1):

You can - by hosting the CLR. I found one set of example code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/calvin_hsia/archive/2006/08/07/691467.aspx) . I have no way of knowing how good the advice there is though, as I've never done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the .NET class thru COM and consume the classes thru COM.